# Android resource compilation failed why?

Tags: java, android, xml

i have tried lots of things but nothing works...

> Android resource compilation failed
>   Output:  C:\Users\user\Desktop\NEW android\test1_tp7\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).
>   Command: C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\2aa1a50b275688b3c8017d916765ab19\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
>           -o \
>           C:\Users\user\Desktop\NEW android\test1_tp7\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
>           C:\Users\user\Desktop\NEW android\test1_tp7\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
>   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Unboutonpresquealéatoire" />


 </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Plus suddenly I can't see my phone device when I run my project. I have tried to download google USB driver, clean project, restart cache but nothing seems to work

[image]

Comment: Can you post that xml code ?

Comment: This error indicates that your xml file probably contains a typo or a spelling error. Have a look at that file (can just be a missing semicolon) or post the content for us to help.

Comment: to show device go to `sdk > platform-tools > adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Comment: where can i find "sdk" ?

Comment: i guess the platform-tools is missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `space` in between ?xml and version, version and encoding in xml declaration. add a space and it should work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: THANKS YOU!do you know why my device is not showing ?

Comment: it might be due to your adb not working, in command prompt go to `sdk > platform-tools > adb kill-server` and again `adb start-server `

Answer (score 0):

Please close the tag `<TabHost>` it will solve your problem

***Follow the below code:***

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Unboutonpresquealéatoire" />


 </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```